# JQuery/JSON Autocomplete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am attempting to do a JQuery Autocomplete function where as you type, the values of the list that you are pulling from gets filtered.  I already have a mock up solution, but the problem that I have is that as I type, the list stays static.  How could I filter the list as the user continues to type?  Below is my code:

```
 $('#search').autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
         $.ajax({
             url: "http://192.168.14.190/testservice/rest/testServices/z1/departments",
             dataType: "json",
             data: { term: request.term },
             success: function (data) {
                 response($.map(data, function (item) {
                     return {
                         label: item.deptName,
                         deptId: item.deptId
                     };
                 }));
             }
         });
     },
     minLength: 2,
     select: function (event, ui) {
         $('#search').val(ui.item.deptName);

     }
 });
```

Comment: `response` should be a function. See here: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Answer (score 0):

Change your response to a function that uses something similar to the keypress function in jQuery:

```
$( "#textfield" ).keypress(function() {  

 //code here


});
```

Comment: I'm a little foggy on what you are trying to show as far as the details are concerned.  Do you have an example?